# Passing selected id to another class

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to return the selected id of my `JComboBox` using Department class as it's reference that return an id. But when I'm trying to return this to another class and use it. It just print the first index and won't listen to my Action that I performed within the JComboBox.

```
public class Frame extends JInternalFrame
{
   JComboBox cbDepartment;
   public Frame()
   {
     super("Frame",true,true,true,true);
     addToPane(getContentPane());
     setVisible(true);
     pack();
   }


   private void addToPane(final Container pane)
   {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      pane.add(panel);

      cbDepartment.setActionCommand("Department");
      cbDepartment.addActionListener(listener);

      panel.add(cbDepartment);

   }

   ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() 
   {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
      {
         if("Department".equals(e.getActionCommand())) 
         {
            Department item = (Department) cbDepartment.getSelectedItem();
            int departmentId = item.getId();

            System.out.println("Your id is " +departmentId);
         }
      }
   }
   //RETURNING FOR ABLE TO USE IN ANOTHER CLASS
   public int getSelectedItem()
   {
      Department item = (Department) cbDepartment.getSelectedItem();
      return item.getId();
   }
}

public class Model
{
   Frame theView;
   public class Model(Frame theView)
   {
      this.theView = theView;
      print();
   }

   public void print()
   {
      int id = theView.getSelectedItem();
      System.out.println(id);
   }
}
```

As you can see above `print()` method only gets the first index even though I register the `JComboBox` with `ActionListener` any reasons why? :)

Comment: Post a [mcve]. An MCVE would have imports, only one **public** class (other classes pasted in after it are fine), one `main(String[])` method to run it all once it compiles cleanly without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to give the combobox a model like DefaultComboBoxModel using

```
cbDepartment.setModel()
```

, then using the function .getmodel() on the combobox you can get the model and then get the selected item .